# Special characters, cmap, copy-paste pdf text to text editor

Tags: fonts, unicode, characters, font-encodings

I have pretty bad issue with special characters. When I copy-paste the text from my pdf file to some other text programs I obtained: `t˛e klas˛e zwi˛azków n˛a` and I expect: `tę klasę związków ną`.

I don't have MWE (I'm trying but I can't reproduce it, my thesis is big and has huge .cls file), so I the most important I have:

```
\RequirePackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\RequirePackage{polski}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[polish]{babel}
```

and I also try `\RequirePackage{cmap}` instead of `\RequirePackage[resetfonts]{cmap}` - the same result. Also - before every compilation I remove all temporary files to be sure that latex produce new one and not based on the old one.

Any ideas what can I do with it? Please, help me.

My fonts: `\RequirePackage{uarial}`. Also I checked editior settings and in TexMaker I have the correct one `utf8`

---

**MWE (I need newtxtext, unless you know something similar which will not destroy all of the special characters, that fonts look like better version of Times New Roman, I need something like this in my thesis):**

```
\documentclass{report}

\input{glyphtounicode} \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}
ąąąęęę ąą ę żż ąąę sprawiają napędzający 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use uarial. That is imho a rather bad package. Try with \usepackage{tgheros} instead. (and replace cmap with `\input{glyphtounicode} \pdfgentounicode=1 `, normally this gives better results).

Comment: so I should use `\input` command in `.cls` file or change it to `Requirepackage`? sorry, I'm pretty bad in packages world, @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Change `\RequirePackage{uarial}` to `\RequirePackage{tgheros}` and remove `\RequirePackage{cmap}` and then check if this improves the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no, it doen't help. I check with system notebook which encoding has `.tex` file and it says that `UTF-8`. I'm confused.

Comment: Then add the input and the pdfgentounicode I mentioned and try again

Comment: Still no `nap˛edzaj˛acy podaż` should be `napędzający podaż`.

Comment: sorry but then something is going on in your document that you didn't told yet. You will have to make a real complete, minimal example.

Comment: maybe something I don't aware of... I'm really trying write properly working MWE

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I found that with `\usepackage{newtxtext}` characters don't work, but I need this package - the font looks completely different without it... because this is one of the requirements for thesis

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer I edited my answer and put short MWE, hope you see my point

Answer (score 2):

newtxtext redefines the \k command and reverts it to the OT1-version. I don't see any reason for it as the fonts have the glyphs. Imho this should be reported to the author.

If I reinstate the T1-definition your chars copy&paste fine. I used standard babel + polish instead of polski as I don't have the time and the will to check if all the catcode changes and redefinitions in polski have side effects.

```
\documentclass{report}

\input{glyphtounicode} \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{a}{161}}
\begin{document}
ąąęęę ąą ę żż ąąę sprawiają napędzający
\sffamily
ąąęęę ąą ę żż ąąę sprawiają napędzający
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but unfortunately the `sffamily` font looks different (a lot different than newtxtext style) so when I put this in my document (which have more than 450 thousands signs) then everything looks different and my graphics and layout (which fitted page perfectly before change) look really bad. To be honest I have just a few (maybe five in all document) ugly `vspace` workaround option to fit something to the page so the spacing/the difference is all about `sffamily` font. I must add that this does not look like nice serif font so if you have a lot of paragraphs on the page it looks bad.

Comment: I used and tested the sffamily font (tgheros) you showed in your minimal example. If you want another one, use another one.

Comment: It's true. I used what you suggested before, I don't have any idea how to use for instance `TeXGyreTermesX` which Cicada mentioned because that MWE below with different fonts don't work when I copy-paste it and run.

Comment: the example from Cicada needs lualatex or xelatex as engine. It won't compile with pdflatex. The fonts used there are opentype fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TeX Gyre Termes` system font with matching `TeX Gyre Termes Math` (use `unicode-math` package and compile with xelatex).

Sample of TeX Gyre fonts:

[image: TeX Gyre sampler]

Some of them also have their own matching math font.

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage{fontspec}% called by unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermesX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newfontface\fonta{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\newfontface\fontb{TeX Gyre Bonum}
%\newfontface\tbm{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\newfontface\fontc{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\newfontface\fontd{TeX Gyre Cursor}
%\newfontface\tdvm{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\newfontface\fonte{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontface\fontf{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontface\fontg{TeX Gyre PagellaX}
\newfontface\fonth{TeX Gyre Schola}
%\newfontface\thm{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\newfontface\fonti{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\newfontface\tim{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newfontface\fontj{TeX Gyre TermesX}
%\usepackage{polski}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\newcommand\eg{ąąąęęę ąą ę żż ąąę sprawiają napędzający}
\newcommand\sample[2]{\bigskip\par #1 #2\\\eg}

\begin{document}
\large
\sample{\fonta}{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\sample{\fontb}{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\sample{\fontc}{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\sample{\fontd}{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\sample{\fonte}{TeX Gyre Heros}
\sample{\fontf}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\sample{\fontg}{TeX Gyre PagellaX}
\sample{\fonth}{TeX Gyre Schola}
\sample{\fonti}{TeX Gyre Termes} $x^2 + y^2 = z^2\cos^2\theta$
\sample{\fontj}{TeX Gyre TermesX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Cicada, I run this MWE in overleaf and the results is without any type of fonts. Are you sure that MWE included every necessary package which I should have to run this properly?

Comment: @Dominika I do not know Overleaf, but maybe it allows you you to load fonts. I compile with xelatex so I can use `fontspec` and unicode system fonts. System is Windows. Output as shown. The packages you need depends on your setup and what tasks you need to do. For example, do you need `polski` package? It is not for unicode according to the manual, and it also changes the definitions of basic things, but it has math formatting for Polish style (like `arc sin`) and I think the math commands could be made standalone. How do others at your institution do it?

Comment: most of them use Word Office to write that kind of the documets. Another group don't take much attention to fonts and use any which have 'ogonek' specific for polski or babel polish package. But I noticed my mistake  (which is not working properly copy-paste option from pdf) after I wrote all of my thesis in `newtxtext` font so when I changed to something which they use like `tgheros` my work crashed (and I mean that long paragraphs take much less or more space and then every table or graphics move to another place in the page or switch to the next page etc.).